# Show page with child terms when clicking parent term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with the following structure:

```
Vocabulary
Parent term 1
    Child term 1.1
        Node tagged with child term 1.1
    Child term 1.2
        Node tagged with child term 1.2
Parent term 2
    Child term 2.1
        Node tagged with child term 2.1
    Child term 2.2
        Node tagged with child term 2.2
Parent term 3 (no children)
    Node tagged with parent term 3
    Node tagged with parent term 3
```

With very limited knowledge I managed to create a view displaying the top-level terms. I would like to click on one of this terms and go to a page displaying either the child terms of the selected parent or, if there are no children, the nodes tagged with that term. After much trial and error all I get when clicking a parent term is a message of 'There is currently no content classified with this term' when I really want to display its children.

In a desperate attempt I created different vocabularies for the terms with child terms and the terms with just nodes underneath. Then I used Views to create different blocks based on the vocabulary name and placed those blocks using the Context module, but this seems like a long shot and I'm sure there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this. By now I have tried several combinations with Taxonomy Menu, Taxonomy Display, arguments and relationships in Views, etc. and I'm not any nearer.

I posted this at the Drupal forums but with no luck yet, I hope someone here can help me figure this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Create a view
2. Add a relationship "Content: Tags", (Tags is vocabulary name I want to show content for)
3. Add a contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" (you can provide a depth of taxonomy term here to display content, if set to 0 it will show content tagged with that particular term id only, if 1 then that particular term id + its first child term content)
4. And provide proper value for this contextual filter.

Here is the screenshot of view I've created:
[image: snap]

Hope this helps.