# Showing content of subterm under parent term

Tags: views

I have following taxonomy structure

```
parent-A
    subterm-1
        sub-subterm-a
        sub-subterm-b
    subterm-2
```

how can I show contents of both the sub-subterm (a and b) when i select/click subterm-1 ; and contents from subterm-1 (sub-subterm a+b) and from subterm-2 when I select parent-A      using views - block display

Comment: What exactly you would like to achieve? Maybe you could use panels and views to do this, maybe you could tag with multiple tags so that parent level content is also tagged with lower level tags?

Comment: I want to display the content of child-term as teaser under that child's parent-term

Comment: have you check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70851/show-all-child-nodes-of-a-taxonomy-term-d7

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most standard way of achieving it but it may help in your case. 
Just try the following code by replacing 24 with a $termid that exists in your case. And see if this gets your work done.

```
    //to get the children of a taxonomy term
    //lets take 24 for example 

      $terms = taxonomy_get_children('24');

      //to get the nodes associated with a termid

     foreach ($terms as $term) {
         $termnodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($term->tid);

         foreach ($termnodes as $termnode) {
              $node = node_load($termnode);
              $node_output = node_view($node);
              print render($node_output, $view_mode = 'teaser'));
        }
  }
```

Comment: I have exactly this problem http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28062/show-page-with-child-terms-when-clicking-parent-term?rq=1

Comment: Do you want to display the nodes in a block or a page ? and if page, is it a normal page or taxonomy-term's page ?

Comment: I want to show nodes in block

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it and try once. If this is not exactly what you want, then the modifications can be done according to your requirements.