# Show all child nodes of a taxonomy term D7

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Ok, so I've been ripping my hair off for the past 2 days now.
I'm developing a web-site with a car catalog which contains the following hierarchy (taxonomy hierarchy):

```
-brand1
--model1
--model2
--model3
-brand2
--model1
--model2
--model3
```

...and so on.

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user selects a parent term (brand), they'll see all the nodes from all the children terms. Currently a parent term doesn't display anything.

I already Googled my problem but none of the solutions seem to work for me (or it's possible I'm doing something wrong).

My configuration is as follows:
Drupal 7.2x
Views 3.7
Taxonomy Menu 1.4 module - used for generating menu trees from vocabularies.
Pathauto 1.2

I use views to display the whole vocabulary - and it works as intended.

Can some one please give me a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this? Especially if it involves Views, as I'm still a noob with Views.

Is it possible the Taxonomy Menu module is causing trouble?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree try this module - This module is also perfectly good for flat lists, particularly if you want to filter them by a view, but it have limitation it only show all the item in single page.

Answer (score 13):

Actually there's a very easy (built-in) method...

1. Go to `admin/structure/views`, find the view named *Taxonomy term*, and enable it
2. Go to `admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit`
3. Click *Advanced* (on the right)
4. Click *Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)*
5. Select a *Depth* of 1 or more
6. Save all your changes

Now, assuming the term id of *Brand 1* is 1, when you visit `www.yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/1`, you should see all the child nodes listed. You can also create path aliases to make paths like `taxonomy/term/1` more "pretty".

Hope that helps...

:)

Comment: YES! IT WORKS!!! Thank you so much, you're a life saver! =)

Answer (score 0):

1. `taxonomy/term/x` -- where x is the term id to show, a number.
2. to show children nodes you need to add a depth variable. The syntax is: `taxonomy/term/x/y` -- where x is the term id to show, and y is the depth to go below x.
3. to show all children nodes. The syntax is: `taxonomy/term/x/all` -- where x is the term id to show.