# Views name or url from taxonomy child terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

i have this vocabulare:

Mother

----Subchild 1

--------Child 1

----Subchild 2

--------Child 2

--------Child 3

how can i get the name or the url from child 1 or child 2, 3? In Views i found a (Term) Taxonomy-Term: parent term relationship/filter only?!

When i use them i get the names of the parent terms of my term. But i want to get the names of the child terms of my term. Any solution?

regards

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is a duplicate question or not, but please feel free to look at the answer I provided for a similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70851/show-all-child-nodes-of-a-taxonomy-term-d7/70874#70874).

Comment: thanks with the contextual filter "has taxo term with depth" set to 1 i got the child names AND the parent names. How can i get the child names only? e.g. i click on subchild 2. The names of subchild 2 AND child 2 AND child 3 appears. But i only want name of Child 1 + 2. Any ideas?

Comment: no one knows a solution for this issue? Maybe its not possible with views ??? :(