# "Taxonomy with depth" view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy tree like this:

- balls

  - basketball

    - color

      - red
      - green
  - volleyball

    - color

      - red
      - green

If a Taxonomy term has children, I want to show them; if there aren't children I want to show the nodes associated with the taxonomy term.

My view settings are the following.

[image: Views settings screenshot]

This is similar to [Show all child nodes of a taxonomy term D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70851/show-all-child-nodes-of-a-taxonomy-term-d7), but I cant get it to work.

I use *Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)*, and I set the depth to 1. It doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do you want to display nodes of those terms? or the terms it self?

Comment: If a Parent term has children then show the children terms

Answer (score 0):

You need Taxonomy Menu Trails module if you have a nested menu tree with taxonomy terms.
Try this: https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails

Comment: I don't see a change. I want to see in /taxonomy/term/x for example the "tree"

Comment: You will also need https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu module

Comment: I don't think i need a module to change the way taxonomy view page show its content(to just show the term child's) . probable you don't understand my explanation

Comment: I am sorry, but yes, I know really don't understand the nature of your question.

Comment: Ok.

I have some taxonomy terms, that they have some child terms. Like a fruit is a parent of apple(child) and a red is a child of apple.

If i go to fruit(mysite.com/fruit) i want to see just the child apple.
if i go to apple(mysite.com/fruit/apple) i want to see the child red/green/etc..
And if a term has no child's , to show the nodes.

Comment: I don't think anyone will need this use case, this seems too personalized and may not be helpful for others.

Comment: Still I would use Taxonomy Menu module to display the menu in one of the regions.

Comment: This is a view configuration.