# Dynamic product catalogues

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

So, I work at a web development agency and we recently decided to give our custom CMS up and start developing with Drupal. Currently, I am developing a wholesale product website. What I need to do is to create some product catalogs without using commerce since we do not need the purchase, checkout and payment features and I thought that using the built-in Content, Taxonomy and Views features we can get our job done.

I have created the product categories in Taxonomy. The main (root) categories are main Taxonomy objects and the subcategories are terms.

I created a custom Content type called: products. In this type I have the following form fields: Product Code, Name, Image, Description and a list field to choose the Terms I would like the product to be displayed in.

I would appreciate some help in order to set the whole structure up as I am still heavily influenced by the custom CMS we used to work on that had similar content management with Joomla!

In conclusion, I would like to:

- Set a sidebar menu up that contains the categories and the subcategories as a tree. I would also like the menu to be updated if any changes occur in the taxonomy (e.g I add a term in taxonomy and it shows up on the menu).
- Set the structure so that when someone clicks on a category that does NOT contain products but subcategories, gets the list of the categories bellow the active one.

I am really looking forward to your answers and I'd like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally instead if all Vocabularies are part of same "Tree" they should be in one "vocabulary" and current items should be displayed as parent terms -> children terms tree structure

**1. regarding first bullet point**

- https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu <- allows adding
  taxonomy items to any menu of your choice
- https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block <- creates a block
  in sidebar with list of your terms of selected vocabulary with
  options such as "Count" that is updated on cron run
- taxonomy_manager <-  I use to mess around with the order of things or
  importing lots of terms it really speeds up the process if you would
  need to move taxonomies from different vocabularies into one :)
  Google it as I cannot post more then 2 links :)

**2. regarding second bullet point**

For that you would need to create "Taxonomy view" instead of content view and set it up so that the categories would be displayed for example: (cant post example as not enough rep)

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to want to leverage [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) for this. You'll make a view to display all of your taxonomy terms in a [block](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/blocks), and put it in the appropriate region in your theme. Views will keep that block updated automatically as any terms are changed.

You might find a module like [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) helpful for your display. And this question is pretty much a duplicate of the second part of your question: ["Taxonomy with depth" view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79647/taxonomy-with-depth-view)

Comment: I will try that today and let you know. It's mainly the fact that I need more experience to completely understand drupal's work flow (which looks brilliant). Thank you.