# How to add content of nested terms to Taxonomy term View

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

By default Drupal 8 taxonomy view doesn't show the nodes of child taxonomy terms. I need to include them but don't know to to modify the view *Taxonomy term (Content)*.

I have the following vocabulary:

```
- Europe
  - Portugal
    - Lisbon
    - Porto
  - Spain
    - Barcelona
    - Madrid
```

Showing all the content related to cities works fine (for example [Barcelona](http://drupaltaxonomynrxzbzfqgx.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/taxonomy/term/16)). But now I want to show a list of content for countries (for example [Spain](http://drupaltaxonomynrxzbzfqgx.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/taxonomy/term/6)) which should include content tagged as city (Barcelona and Madrid). And the same with continents, a list for [Europe](http://drupaltaxonomynrxzbzfqgx.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/taxonomy/term/1) should include content tagged as Lisbon, Porto, Barcelona, Madrid, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70851/show-all-child-nodes-of-a-taxonomy-term-d7) and it is almost the same than for D7:

1. Edit the existing view **Taxonomy Term** (admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit)
2. In *Advanced*, add the field **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)** using all the settings from already added *Content: Has taxonomy term ID using the same settings*. You can limit the depth by setting the depth parameter.
3. Remove old field *Content: Has taxonomy term ID using the same settings*
4. Set **Use aggregation** to yes to avoid duplicates